# How to make a OpenVPN tunnel between home and server network with IPv6 support

Tags: openvpn, ipv6

I'm build a OpenVPN tunnel between my home network and my server. Here's my current scenario:

```
Server
(IPv4: 198.x.x.5)
IPv6: 2001:xxx:xxx:xxx::abcd) <-----------> My ISP (CGN) <------------> Home Gateway <--------> Home computers
(Public Pool: 2001:xxx:xxx::/64)     (Some public IP addresses)        (172.16.6.22)          (192.168.99.x/24)
```

Server has a single public IPv4 address, a public IPv6 address and a global routable IPv6 IP address block. This is the left side of OpenVPN tunnel.

Home Gateway is a Linux machine with OpenVPN installed. This device runs radvd(IPv6) and dhcpd(IPv4). OpenVPN tunnel endpoint is here. It also supply Internet access for Home Computers with *native IPv4/IPv6 dual-stack Internet access* experience. This device should get and allocate a block of IPv6 addresses.

How to configure my OpenVPN to implement this?

**EDIT:**

I googled and found something like [this](https://www.zagbot.com/openvpn_ipv6_tunnel.html) but it seems that's for the scenario below which is different than the case above:

```
Server
(IPv4: 198.x.x.5)
IPv6: 2001:xxx:xxx:xxx::abcd) <-----------> My ISP (CGN) <--------->   Home computers
(Public Pool: 2001:xxx:xxx::/64)     (Some public IP addresses)        (172.16.6.22)          (192.168.99.x/24)
```

In this case, each Home Computer need to install OpenVPN and run it as client.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have routable IPV6 addresses at both sites, then consider using an IPV6 tunnel broker instead of a VPN tunnel. It tried VPN myself and it was fraught with problems.  Look into sixxs and hurricane electric. They can offer you IPV6 blocks.

Comment: I know there are plenty of tunnel brokers available, but I still want to build my own one. VPN is just one approach, if you have better idea, please let me know :-)